# Different behavior on the way I launch the program

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, cmd, ncurses

I would create a different behavior based on the system and on the way a software is launched. I'm on Windows and I use Eclipse as IDE.
I would have different behaviors on the base of the OS (Linux or Windows). This should be easy to do. This is the code I founded:

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    //linux code goes here
#elif _WIN32
    // windows code goes here
#else

#endif
```

But, I would also have a different behaviour on the base of the way I launch the software.
I mean, if I launch the software from my Eclipse, the software has to do something, if I launch it from Windows command line (cmd), another.
In my specific case, I need this type of behavior becouse I would use `ncurses` lib to my output. I would have `cout` stream when I lauch the software from Eclipse and ncurses output when I launch it from `cmd.exe`.
Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Really? I explained everything in my question.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a command-line parameter when you launch your program.
I.e.

> > yourprogram --devmode

Launch your program with --devmode from Eclipse IDE, do not specify the parameter when launched normally from the command prompt/shell.

Comment: The other solution is to use environment variables; but I don't think there are any others